# Failed to restart supervisor.service: Unit not found CentOS 7

Tags: supervisord

I am trying to use laravel queue:work on live server and keep alive the work using Supervisor. After configuration it shows  as follows:

```
[root@vmi485931 supervisord.d]# sudo supervisorctl reload
Restarted supervisord
[root@vmi485931 supervisord.d]# sudo service supervisor restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart supervisor.service
Failed to restart supervisor.service: Unit not found.
```

Any clue?

Comment: It's supervisor***d*** not supervisor. So `service supervisord restart` or, more properly, `systemctl restart supervisord`. Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 0):

there are some package missing in Centos 7. i had some issue on centos 7 and i fixed issue with this commands :

1- need python-meld3 package

sudo rpm -ivh https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/p/python-meld3-0.6.10-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

2-needs supervisor lib.

sudo rpm -ivh  https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/s/supervisor-3.4.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to restart the processes that are run by supervisor, run
`sudo supervisorctl restart all`
You can use supervisor process name instead of 'all' to restart a specific process.

If you are trying to restart supervisor itself,`sudo systemctl restart supervisor` should work.